# Why to stop a particle filter if the robot does not move?

Tags: particle-filter

It is clear it is not a good idea to do resampling in a particle filter if the robot is not moving (there is no action), as the particles will converge towards a simple particle.

However, Probabilistic Robotics book quickly mentions "It is usually a good idea to stop measurement integration if the robot does not move". However, I am not able to fully understand why.

My only guess is that, if robot does not move the sampling (which not resampling) will give the same particles. Therefore, is there any other negative effect other than wasting computational power? Because in a world with lots of noise I think it might be helpful to keep the sampling running to have move proper weights over time.

Comment: Integrating something forever would/could potentially result in some huge number to deal with. Do not run integrators when not in direct use.

Comment: @GürkanÇetin thanks for the response, but that does not make sense within the context of my question. "Integration" here means "taking into account", not literally calculating an integral.

Comment: That's alright then. No problems. I'm more into flight controllers, and there you really stop processing if not running, not to cause any unintended consequences.